# The difference between two positive definite matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Given that M is a real symetric positive definite matrix what can we say about the relationship between the two terms below?

1. $ x^TMx$
2. $\sqrt{ x^TM^2x}$

I am trying to find conditions when the second term is bigger the the first one.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By [definition of a positive definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), $x^TMx\geq0$.
2. Since $M$ is symetric, $M^T=M$, hence we have
   $$x^TM^2x=x^TMMx=x^TM^TMx=\left(Mx\right)^TMx=\|Mx\|^2.$$

For your last question, there is no general rule to say if one of these numbers is greater than the other. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, take $M=I_n$ (the identity matrix) ; then
$$x^TMx=x^Tx=\|x\|^2,\quad\sqrt{x^TMx}=\sqrt{x^Tx}=\|x\|$$
and all depends on the fact that $\|x\|\leq1$ or $\|x\|>1$.